# Python print both def instead of one, i want it to either answer to yes or no

Tags: python, function

Hello im new to Python it's my first time trying to write something, i want this to be able to either answer to yes or no but when i type either yes or no it always print:

nice

oh no

````
def yes1(): 
   print("nice")

def no1():
   print("oh no")

input("Welcome are you ok ?\nyes/no:")

yes = yes1
yes1()

no = no1
no1()```
````

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you follow a good basic Python tutorial, there would be too much to cover here and SO is not the right place for that. You can find some recommendations at https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend you have a look at basic programming tutorials. `if`/`elif`/`else` statement knowledge is invaluable.

But as a temporary solution while you learn, have a look at the following and see if it makes sense to you:

```py
def yes1(): 
   print("nice")

def no1():
   print("oh no")

user_input = input("Welcome are you ok ?\nyes/no:")

if user_input.lower()=="yes":
    yes1()
elif user_input.lower()=="no":
    no1()
```

Answer (score 0):

So the way i have done it is so, program ask for Yes/No and then runs and if statement on whether its if Yes or elif No and depending on what it is it prints Nice or oh no...

```
def yes1(): 
   print("nice")

def no1():
   print("oh no")

question = input("Welcome are you ok ?\nyes/no: ")

if question == 'yes' or  'Yes':
  yes1()

elif question == 'nN' or  'no':
  no1()
```